# Duplicates using Arrays and TextFile

Tags: c#

I'm having an issue outputting my current code in Unity. I'm using an output text field to display the amount of duplicates per number.

Been browsing feeds and haven't gotten what I needed so here I am asking this now.

```
public int whatIndex,count;
public Text output;

public void Start()
{
    string Random = "";

    //reading the text file
    string Duplicates = "duplicates.txt";
    string Duplicates_Path = Application.dataPath + "/Text_Files/" + Duplicates;
    string[] Numbers = File.ReadAllLines(Duplicates_Path);

    foreach(string number in Numbers)
    {
        Random += number;
    }

    output.text = Random + "\n";

    //array for text
    for (whatIndex = 0; whatIndex < Duplicates.Length; whatIndex++)
    {
        Debug.Log(Numbers[whatIndex] + "\n");
        Debug.Log("The number " + Numbers[whatIndex].ToString() + " appears " + count + 
            " times(s)");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your question "how to count duplicate characters?"

Comment: `Duplicates` is the name of the text file, so when you do `for (whatIndex = 0; whatIndex < Duplicates.Length; whatIndex++)`, you're iterating exactly 14 times, which is the length of the string representing the file name, `"duplicates.txt"` (it has 14 characters).

Comment: Its to count how many times a number repeats in the array for each number.

Comment: It seems strange that you name a `string` type `Numbers`. A more representative name might be `fileLines`. And then `foreach(string fileLine in fileLines)`. Just to be clear that we are not necessarily dealing with a numberic type.

Comment: What is `count`, and where does it ever get initialized or modified?

Comment: As of now "count" is a place holder in the text that we displayed. It should be representing the amount of times that number appeared (duplicates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to count occurrence for each number which is available in duplicate.txt files. Please find below code, i have tweak your code little bit e.g. file path and debug.log and remove unnecessary variables. you can see [input here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvO7q.png) and [output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUSZa.png):

```
public void Start()
    {           
        Dictionary<int, int> numberCount = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        //reading the text file
        string Duplicates = "duplicates.txt";
        string Duplicates_Path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Text_Files\\" + Duplicates;
        string[] Numbers = File.ReadAllLines(Duplicates_Path);

        foreach (string number in Numbers)
        {

            int temp = int.Parse(number);
            if (numberCount.ContainsKey(temp))
            {
                numberCount[temp] = numberCount[temp] + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                numberCount[temp] = 1;
            }               
        }

        //array for text
        foreach(KeyValuePair<int,int> item in numberCount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The number " + item.Key.ToString() + " appears " + item.Value.ToString() +
                " times(s)");               
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what you want to achieve but I guess, there are some problems with your code (see after code).

### Example Snippet:

First of all, you can try to use this code to get an idea about one solution to get the duplicates and the number of duplicates after reading the text file by using a Dictionary from System.Collections.Generic:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // String array with duplicates
        string[] Numbers = {"1","1", "2", "6","1","7","1","7","8","3"};
        Dictionary<string, int> KeyNumbersValueCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        foreach(string number in Numbers)
        {
            if(KeyNumbersValueCount.ContainsKey(number))
                KeyNumbersValueCount[number] += 1;
            else
                KeyNumbersValueCount.Add(number, 1);
        }   

        foreach(var NumberAndCount in KeyNumbersValueCount)
            Console.WriteLine("The number " + NumberAndCount.Key + " appears " + 
NumberAndCount.Value + " times(s)");
    }
}
```

[running example code above](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FDt7eH)

### Open Issues with your code from the question:

1. Do you need count? It is initializied but never used
2. If you don't need "whatIndex", then you can also initialize it within the for loop:

---

```
for (int whatIndex = 0; whatIndex < Duplicates.Length; whatIndex++)
 {
     // do s.th.
 }
```

---

3. You are trying to iterate over length of the string "Duplicates", which is "duplicates.txt" and therefore it has a length of 14. I guess you want to iterate over your strings in your file.
4. In your case, Random doesn't really have a function. You could also use File.ReadAllText instead of File.ReadAllLines and hand it over to output.text, if you only want to print it. [See Microsoft Refs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netcore-3.1).